# Уникальный ID для попап в карточке товара JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, magnific-popup

У меня на карточке товара есть попап (magnific-popup) с подробным описанием этого товара, попап  привязывается по id. Я через $.each(menu,function(key,item){} вывовожу информацию на страницу, все работает, карточки с разными данными из массива, но попап открывается естественно одинаковый для каждой из них, потому-что данные (href="#product-popup" для карточка и id="product-popup" для попап) одинаковые.

Как прописать, а главное как вставить в код это, чтобы генерился разный id для каждой карточки? Я не так давно начала работать с js, пожалуйста, помогите.

Comment: Добавьте код вывода самих "карточек"

Answer (score 1):

Нашла решение. Создала объект[image: id_popup] id_popup

[image: добавление в основной код]